# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php

I have a problem with PDO, and I see absolutely nowhere he comes. I can not question my MySQL database. Just to test I used the following code (having quite sour previously configured the parameters for the connection:

```
protected function createMigrationsTable()
{
    $this->pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS migrations (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        migration VARCHAR(255),
        created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )  ENGINE=INNODB;");
}
```

The connection is made correctly with MySQL but after migration, I get this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT7zs.png)

Comment: you need to select database first. in your connection parameters, check if "dbname" is correctly defined. and make sure that the database exists on mysql server

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the database exists.

Comment: in driver constructor. do you pass the dbname parameter? 
Here is the example
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct#example-1030

Comment: I am writing in .env `DB_DSN = mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;db_name=mvc`

Comment: cab you share the database connection code?

Comment: you're running this file outside xamp using system-installed PHP and your database is most probably in xamp's PHPMyAdmin. To prevent this error you need to access this file using either xampp's PHP path or through browser (again using xampp running port) @MahmoudKhosravi check this

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwH1Q.png

Comment: exec('`which mysql_config` --socket'); you can also use this line to check which socket your code is using

Comment: so my point is please make sure you're specifying correct database details and most probably error lies in the socket that you're using. Either run file xampp's PHP path or through xampp browser or specify xampp MySQL socket in your connection properly

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/flg5m.png

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's connected

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Are you using a PHP framework, and if so which? How have you configured it?  If not, how/where did you configure your DB connection?  There is no info here that we can use to help - eg right now the only answer we can say is "you have no database configured".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHECK the DSN string. For MySQL it should look like this:

mysql:host=hostname_or_ip;port=XXXX;**dbname**=name_of_db

or after establishing connection, make:

```
  $this->pdo->exec("USE database_name");
```